# The cuberoot symbol in java string

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am making a calculator in Android.

For this purpose I am using various buttons, three of which are for the symbol of PI, square root and cube root.

Now when I test this as a simple code in netbeans:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("\u03C0");  
      System.out.println("\u221A");  
      System.out.println("\u221B");  
    }
}
```

I get the expected output:

run:

π

√

∛

However when I do similar display for android development using eclipse:

```
public static String[] button_text = new String[]{
    "^",        "ln(",      "log(",     "\u221A(",
    "\u03C0",       "x!",       "abs(",     "\u221B("   
};

public static String[] button_text_values = new String[]{
    "^",        "ln(",      "log(",     "\u221A(",
    "\u03C0",       "!",        "abs(",     "\u221B("   
};
```

The buttons pi, sqrt do display the symbol. On pressing them, the symbols also appear in the textview.

However the same does not hold for the cube root button. It just displays the bracker "(".
On pressing it the textview also displays only the bracket.

However all calculations go correct.

That is pressing cuberoot and then 8 does give the result 2.

This means the cuberoot does exist in the expression string, but is not being displayed in buttons or the textview.

How do I correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the character exists in the device font?

Comment: how do I check that?
And if square root is displayed then shouldn't cube root also be displayed?

Comment: Nope.. one character does not beget another :) and Simon has your answer down below... as I suspected. Char not there.

Comment: what does a font have to do with this? the strings are unicode and if they are not getting displayed, then probably it could be a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font you are using probably does not contain the cube root character.  Try a different font:

```
tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewOne);
bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOne); 
Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DejaVuSans.ttf");
tv1.setTypeface(font); 
bt1.setTypeface(font);
```

Also see this:

http://tinkering-is-fun.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/adding-support-for-more-characters-in.html